# Derivative of trace of tensor

Tags: derivatives, tensors, trace

Given a rank-2 tensor $Q$, how would one work out $\frac{d Tr(Q^2)}{dQ}$? If the tensor $Q$ was traceless and symmetric (ie $Tr(Q)=0$ and $Q=Q^T$) , would this change things?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Let $\phi(\mathbf{Q}) 
= \mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{Q}^2)
= \mathbf{I}:\mathbf{Q}^2
$.
We use here the Frobenius inner product and $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix.

The differential writes
$$
d\phi = 
\mathbf{I}:\mathbf{Q} (d\mathbf{Q}) +
\mathbf{I}:(d\mathbf{Q})\mathbf{Q}
$$
We deduce the gradient is
$$
\mathbf{Q}+\mathbf{Q}^T
$$
If the tensor is traceless, so does the gradient.
If the tensor is symmetric, the gradient writes $2\mathbf{Q}$.